# domain using level curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f(x,y)=4x^2-y^2$. The problem is to determine the range of this function using the idea of level curves. So one sets $f(x,y)=D$, where $D\in\mathbb{R}$. What values can $D$ take?

Answer (score 1):

The range is $\mathbb{R}$

- if $D<0$ then $f(0,\sqrt{|D|})=-|D|=D$
- if $D>0$ then $f(1/2\sqrt{D})=D$
- if $D=0$ take $f(0,0)=0$

Comment: How would you approach the function $g(x,y)=x^2+4y^2-9$?

Comment: $x^2+y^2$ is strictly positive. So the range of $g(x,y)=x^2+4y^2−9$? is $[-9, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this. Suppose we have that $f(x,y)=1-(x^2+y^2-4)^2$. What's the range of this function? One first notes that $f(0,0)=-15$ and that $f(x,y)\leq 1,\;\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm guessing that the range of $f$ is $(-\infty,-15]$. Is this correct? This function has a "dip" in the middle.

Comment: It is true that $f(x,y)\leq1$. But what is $f(0,2)$?